# errors thrown inside npm mysql library causes crash - throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, try-catch, throw

I have been using the `mysql` library for a project now. I noticed something.

```js
    try {
        let number = req.params.number;
        number = parseInt(number, 10);
        if (number && number % 10 == 0 && number > 0) {
            pool.query(
                `select * from posts limit ${number - 10}, ${10}`,
                function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw "Url incorrect, ensure that the params % 10 == 0";
                    }
                    // if (!result.length) {
                    //  throw "No more posts available";
                    // }
                    const response = result.map(function (item) {
                        return {
                            ...item,
                            files: item.files
                                ? item.files.split(",").map(function (item) {
                                        return (
                                            "http://localhost:4000/files/" +
                                            item
                                        );
                                  })
                                : [],
                        };
                    });
                    res.json({
                        valid: true,
                        data: response,
                        nextPage: number + 10,
                    });
                }
            );
        } else {
            throw "Something went wrong";
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({ valid: false, msg: err });
    }
```

This is the part of my code. Here when result's length is 0 I throw errors and console.log it in the catch block. But I noticed it crashes the program and prints `` throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^
No more posts available
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE....... `` in the terminal. I don't understand what mistake am I making?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the catch block.

Comment: okay. I have added the whole block

Comment: any suggestions? still cant figure out where am i going wrong